# Emberjs Textarea 2 way binding with data that needs to be a getter

Tags: ember.js

I am using [Emberjs Textarea](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Ember.Templates.components/methods/Textarea?anchor=Textarea) which has 2 way binding with the `@value` attribute.

The data I am passing into the value is from an argument and therefore needs to be return from a getter before I can use it in the template.

My question is how do I use 2 way binding with a getter. I keep on getting error messages stating that `Cannot set property inputText of #<InputComponent> which has only a getter`

I have tried to use `{{mut}}` and tried to create a `setter` for the `getter` but nothing has worked.

The post requests actually work but I still get those annoying errors in the console.

```
// Component JS    
get inputText() {
  return this.args.text;
}

// Component Template

<Textarea @value={{this.inputText}} @focusOut={{this.postRequest}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like setting the args value directly in the template will work.

```
<Textarea @value={{@inputText}} @focusOut={{this.postRequest}} />
```

Comment: The `@` sigil is a shortcut for `this.args` in a template, so `@inputText` should work.